# ultimo registro Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

Como saber o ultimo registro do ID na tabela e jogar o numero em uma textblock?

```
 using (_connection = new MySqlConnection("Database=test;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=teste;SslMode=None;"))
        {
            System.Text.EncodingProvider ppp;
            ppp = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);

            _connection.Open();
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ???? FROM user", _connection);

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    textBlock.Text = (reader.GetString("id"));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM user ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra opção seria:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM user
```